# How to upload multiple files in Play Framework using Java

Tags: java, playframework

Hi i have been trying to upload image file in Play Framework. I have been trying out with Java File Upload since morning but unable to do so. I have seen `[JavaFileUpload][1]` tutorial available on framework website. But i am still not successful. Here is my code which i am trying to run:

```
Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();        
List<Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart> fileParts = body.getFiles();
     for (Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart filePart : fileParts) {
             String filename = filePart.getFilename();
             File file = filePart.getFile(); //error comes on this line

             if (filePart.getFilename().toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")) { 
                //saving here but how?

             } else {
                  return badRequest("Invalid request, only PNGs are allowed.");

             }
         }
```

but problem is that whenever i try to get the file i am having this conversion error:

```
java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.io.File
```

Anyone can guide me in the direction? if we see the official document there is no proper documentation on how to upload multiple files. If anyone can show me some website which can helps me in that direction that will be also helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after lots of trouble i was able to figure out the answer to my question. Here i am going to post the answer so it helps other people searching the answer to the same problem i faced

The controller function call which will upload the files looks like this:

```
Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();        
List<Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart> fileParts = body.getFiles();
     for (Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart filePart : fileParts) {
             if (filePart.getFilename().toLowerCase().endsWith(".png")) { 
             String filename = filePart.getFilename();
Files.write(Paths.get(filename + ".png"), readContentIntoByteArray((File) filePart.getFile()));

             } else {
                  return badRequest("Invalid request, only PNGs are allowed.");

             }
         }
```

I am using a function call to read the content of the file into byte array and save them inside the file:

```
private static byte[] readContentIntoByteArray(File file) {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    try {
        //convert file into array of bytes
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileInputStream.read(bFile);
        fileInputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bFile;
}
```

Remember you can choose whatever the path you want to save the file at `Paths.get(filename + ".png")`

Comment: could you post your imports

Comment: @AndreasFritsch Sorry i don't understand your question

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Play 2.4 and

```
FilePart filePart = request().body().asMultipartFormData()
            .getFile("myFileKey");
File file = filePart.getFile();
```

With Play 2.2 I used for multiple file uploads:

```
MultipartFormData mfd = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
List<FilePart> filePartList = mfd.getFiles();
FilePart filePart = filePartList.get(0);
```

Comment: isn't that when you have only one file? I have multiple files coming in HTML form array element named `photos[]`. Can you tell me how will i be able to iterate through them? if i have multiple files?

Comment: I added code that I used in Play 2.2 for multiple file uploads but I haven't used it with any more recent Play version. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the update actually i came back to the same place that is having `java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.io.File` error of wrong type object even if i use the above code. after `FilePart filePart = filePartList.get(0);` i tried fetching data into a file object using `File realFile = filePart.getFile();` and again got the same error which i am facing since start

Comment: Maybe your error message is right. Maybe you have no file objects in your body? How do you upload the files?

Comment: I do have files in my body content i was able to get the names and content i dumped the values. But still thanks everyone i got the answer i am going to add the answer below in a few minutes